Is Neumann's expansion of an entire function unique?
Let $f$ be an entire function. Then there exist numbers $a_0,a_1,\ldots$, independent of $z$, such that
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n(z),\quad \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$$
where $J_n$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order $n$. This is called Neumann's expansion of $f$.
Question
Given $f$, are the numbers $a_n$ unique?
Thoughts
I took a look at Abramowitz and Stegun and Whittaker and Watson; in each book they mention the expansion but say nothing about the uniqueness of the coefficients. It would be nice if Neumann's expansions turn out to be unique just as Taylor's expansions of entire functions. I figured out that it is sufficient to prove that, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n(z)=0\implies \forall n\in\mathbb{N}:a_n=0;$$

I would appreciate any help. Whittaker and Watson took the obvious "reversed implication" and arrived at one possible integral representation of $a_n$ in terms of "Neumann polynomials", but I don't know if that helps.
Edit:
The question has already been answered on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/478158/uniqueness-of-neumann-series

as usual look for a definition of $a_n$ via an integral which gives you the unicity; in this case you can find it here https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Neumann_series   ; btw if you read Whittaker and Watson carefully, you will also see that $a_n$ are determined uniquely though it is not explicitly mentioned at the end

@Conrad Can you please elaborate? I've seen a proof that if $a_n=\text{something}$ then $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n(z)$, not the other way around.

if you look at the link given you will see that $\pi i a_n=\int_C f(t)O_n(t)dt$ for $n \ge 1$ where $C$ is a small circle around zero, while $a_0=f(0)$ (or with $O_0(t)=1/t$ one also gets  $2\pi i a_0=\int_C f(t)O_0(t)dt$  in a similar way we have a different constant for the first coefficient of a sine-cosine Fourier series); this immediately gives that $a_n=0$ if $f$ identical zero (again similar to the Fourier case)

I think you are misunderstanding the integral formula; note that for $m >n$ we have $\int_C J_m(t)O_n(t)dt=0$ because the integrand is analytic; next integrating by parts and noting that the curve $C$ is closed so there is no evaluation we get $\int_C J_0(t)O_1(t)dt=-\int_C J_0(t)O_0'(t)dt=\int_C J_0'(t)O_0(t)dt=0$ since $J_0'=-J_1$ and the above with $m=1, n=0$; continue inductively to show that $\int_C J_1(t)O_1(t)dt=\pi i$ and then it follows  $\int_C J_0(t)O_2(t)dt=0$ etc eventually arriving at $\int_C J_m(t)O_m(t)dt=\pi i, m \ge 1$ ($2\pi i, m=0$) and $\int_C J_m(t)O_n(t)dt=0, m \ne n$

then the integral formula for $a_n$ just follows integrating its expression against $O_n$, switching series and integral  (uniform convergence on $C$) and using the orthogonality above; now this shows that the Neumann expansion is unique assuming some kind of nice convergence (eg uniform on compacts etc) so indeed there is the question if a non-uniform (just pointwise) convergence is possible - this I do not know if it's known or not (the corresponding result for Fourier series is quite deep and difficult) but I have no idea what use such a representation would have

@Conrad It doesn't need to have a "use", I don't mind if it's only pointwise convergent. But thanks for your time.

I suspect that like in the Fourier series case there should be a unicity theorem for pointwise convergence too but I am not sure that has been researched since Neumann series do not seem to have caught the attention like Fourier series - again maybe looking at original papers or asking an expert in complex analysis (eg ask on MO as a reference question since maybe some expert there in complex analysis will know) would help - for me complex analysis is a tool to be used in combinatorics or number theory so I see no interest in a series that doesn't converge nicely
